# Running Python scripts inside Android Studio

Tags: python, android-studio

I am running Android Studio 2.2.3 I need to run Python scripts during my development to process some data files. The final APK does not need to run Python in the device.

At the moment I run the scripts from a terminal or from PyDev for Eclipse, but I was looking for a way of doing it from Android Studio.

There seems to be a way to do this, as when I right-click on a `.py` file and select the 'Run' option, an 'Edit configuration' dialog opens where I can configure several options. The problem is that I cannot specify the Python interpreter, having to select it from a combo box of already configured Python SDKs. While there is no interpreter selected, there is an error message stating *"Error: Please select a module with a valid Python SDK"*.

I managed to create Java modules for my project, but not Python ones (I do have the Python Community Edition plugin installed). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to run the scripts and not to edit them, the easiest way to do so is to configure an external tool through Settings | Tools | External Tools. This doesn't require the Python plugin or any Python-specific configuration; you can simply specify the command line to execute. External tools appear as items in the Tools menu, and you can also assign keyboard shortcuts to them using Settings | Keymap.

Comment: Hey thanks, I was expecting to to edit, run and debug, placing breakpoints, etc.

Comment: I don't think this would actually work. To debug a Python script in a Java module in IntelliJ IDEA, you'd need to create a Python facet and specify the Python SDK in the facet settings, and Android Studio lacks the UI for creating facets.