# How to run Python file(.py) in Android Studio?

Tags: python, android-studio-2.2

I am new in Python.I want to run python file(.py) on android device using Android Studio.
Any tutorial will be more useful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python scripts inside Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166406/running-python-scripts-inside-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such support for running Python on Android devices. Best way, currently, is to use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/whatis.html) which is designed to run python in Java environment.